# Using a previously defined #define in a new #define in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Are there any potential issues/dangers in doing something such as

```
#define SAMPLERATE 32 // Sample rate in hertz
#define ONE_MINUTE ( SAMPLERATE * 60 )
#define FIVE_MINUTES ( ONE_MINUTE * 5 )
```

My compiler doesn't issue any errors or warnings.  It's very nice because I can change one `#define` value (SAMPLERATE) and all the others get set to what they need to be with no other changes.  I'm just not entirely sure if this is best practice or safe.

Comment: there's not problem at all

Comment: You can check it by yourself - look in assembly.

Comment: That's exactly what you should be doing, nothing to worry about

Comment: So, every 32 ticks is a second?

Comment: @FiddlingBits Yes, for this example.  I could eventually increase or decrease my sample rate, thus making this implementation nice because that's the only #define I would need to change.

Comment: @Oilyraincloud So, this is a smart way of handling varying sample rates then.

Comment: @Oilyraincloud You may also consider utilizing your IDE (if you're using one) to create different configurations. This would allow you to define `CONFIG_SAMPLERATE_1` and define pre-processor directives using the IDE -> generally under configuration properties or something similar. Then you could easily switch between configurations without changing source code.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Yes, but only in the sense of development.  Eventually I will settle on one after some vigorous testing is done and keep it there.  If the application were to have a varying sample rate, this method wouldn't be good because it uses constant values.

Comment: @Oilyraincloud By varying, I meant you would vary it, not the system. :-D

Comment: It would be fixed once it was compiled. You're not changing it at run-time!

Comment: @FiddlingBits Gotcha!  At least now it's stated so that if someone else comes reading it they will understand.

Comment: Yep!  I don't want this to change nor be able to be changed at run-time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `#define` is handled by the pre-processor. The pre-processor is run prior to compilation and can perform simple mathematical operations and copy/paste of code. For instance, you could do the following with your example:

`int myVar = SAMPLERATE;`

The pre-processor would simply paste `32` where `SAMPLERATE` is before being compiled.

This mechanism is powerful in the sense that you have now created a name for an integer value. This adds meaning for both you and future developers. It also allows you to make changes in one place instead of many.

Just be sure to `#define SAMPLERATE 32` prior to any other `#define` statements that may use `SAMPLERATE`.

Comment: So if I did `int myVar = FIVE_MINUTES;` would `FIVE_MINUTES` be replaced with 32 * 60 * 5 or just the value 9600?

Comment: You're answer is correct, but perhaps a little deep for the question that was asked.

Comment: @bblincoe: no - that is not true - the preprocessor just does text substitution. The compiler however will normally reduce any compile time constant expression to a single value.

Comment: @PaulR Yes my mistake. I was thinking in terms of evaluating expressions such as in the case of #if statements.

Comment: @PaulR: The preprocessor substitutes preprocessor tokens, not text. E.g., `#define LT <` followed by `1 LT< 1` will not result in the equivalent of `1 << 1`.

Answer (score 10):

Macros are NEVER expanded in a `#define` statement.  When you have `#define` like:

```
#define ONE_MINUTE ( SAMPLERATE * 60 )
```

That defines the macro `ONE_MINUTE` with an expansion (body) of `( SAMPLERATE * 60 )`.  Whether there is a macro called `SAMPLERATE` defined elsewhere in your program or not is completely irrelevant.  The exisitence (or non-existence) of such a macro has no effect.

Instead, when a macro is USED (and the macro expanded), the result of that expansion is rescanned for other macros to expand.  So all that matters is whether `SAMPLERATE` is defined at the point at which `ONE_MINUTE` is USED.

Answer (score 0):

#define constants (object-like macros) are used by the pre-processor to substitute the identifier with the token list specified . #defines can also take parameters. These are called function-like macros. The advantage of such macros is that they are replaced in-line something that you can't always guarantee with normal functions. Object-like macros are used frequently in conditional compilation. The drawback of macros in my opinion is that they are not type safe. When used carefully  however they can be a great help.

Here is an example of macros making your life easier.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static const unsigned char BYTES[256] = {
#define A(n) n, n+1, n+1, n+2
#define B(n) A(n), A(n+1), A(n+1), A(n+2)
#define C(n) B(n), B(n+1), B(n+1), B(n+2)
C(0), C(1), C(1), C(2)
};

int main() {
  unsigned char BYTE = 0b01011101;
  printf("The byte 01011101 has %d set bits.\n",BYTES[BYTE]);
}
```

Comment: Kind of off-topic answer, no?

Comment: Maybe I got the question wrong. I am just stating that defines are useful and used a lot and the code was just an example I had ready. Well the example uses macros instead of simple constants so maybe you are referring to that?

Comment: The OP wasn't asking about macros.