# Does order matter when #defines are using other #defines?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, operator-precedence

According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030041/using-a-previously-defined-define-in-a-new-define-in-c), the following code is legit:

```
#define three 3
#define nine three*3

int main()
{
    std::cout << nine;
    return 0;
}
```

And sure, it compiles and runs fine. However, the answer to mentioned question also states that one should be careful about the order of such `#define` directives, and one that will be used in other `#define`s should be defined before them. But the following code:

```
#define nine three*3
#define three 3

int main()
{
    std::cout << nine;
    return 0;
}
```

Also compiles and runs fine, and it prints "9".

Is my compiler letting me off easy, or does the order indeed not matter with #defines  that use other `#define`s? Would the compilation fail on a more complicated project?

One thing worth mentioning is that the mentioned question speaks of **C**, whilst my code is in C++. Is that where the (supposed) differences in behavior come from?

Comment: See Chris Dodds answer in the linked question.

Comment: @erenon Oh, indeed, it gives a more in-depth look into this mechanic. Good you pointed it out.

Comment: A more complicated project does not imply more complicated macros. You can get small projects with complex macros and large projects with simple macros.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`three` macro need be only defined before use of `nine` macro.
You can even change `three` before every use of `nine`:

```
#define nine three*3
#define three 3

int main()
{
    std::cout << nine; //9
#undef three
#define three 4
    std::cout << nine; //12
#undef three
    //no `three` macro defined here
    int three = 2;
    std::cout << nine; //three * 3 == 6
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The preprocessor does multiple runs and only finishes when no other occurrences of all defines are found. Thus, your code samples both work but the preprocessor needs one more run in case of the second one. You have to be careful with recursive defines. The ppc then would never exit.

Comment: you cant made preprocessor do infinite loop. He stop when he spot same token that he previously expanded. eg. `#define Foo Foo` result in `Foo`.

Answer (score 3):

This steps would be done in the preprocessor step and all literals would be replaced with their value. This can be verified if we compile with the option:

> $ g++ -save-temps basic.cpp -o out

This is the output after preprocessor step(basic.ii file):

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << 3*3;
    return 0;
}
```

for your sample program. So order should not be matter as it is kind of find and replace and it is getting done prior to actual compilation of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is because of two step parser. In first step it tries to resolve all the symbol and in second step actual value is placed.